# Trying to Pull a specific range of cells from another work book

Tags: vba, excel

first timer here, so go easy on me :)
Only been using VBA for a few months on work projects and I have hit a wall with what I can google, figured Id post the problem here.

I have a button that will open a source workbook and copy a specific range of cells from the source workbook to the destination workbook. This range of cells to be copied is determined by a for loop that starts at row 2 and loops to the last row of data. I have this code working in another project, but it appears to not want to run when its targeted at a different workbook.
Appreciate the help and any advice on the code in general would be welcome :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastRow, i, erow As Integer
Dim filename As String
Dim fname As Variant
Dim dwbk, swbk As Workbook
Dim sws, dws As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range

    Set dwbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set dws = dwbk.Sheets("Call OFF")

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandling

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FileArray = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select file(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

            For Each fname In FileArray

                Set swbk = Workbooks.Open(fname)
                Set sws = swbk.Sheets("Allocations")
                lastRow = sws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To lastRow

                    Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "B")).Select
                    Selection.Copy

                    dwbk.Sheets("CALL OFF").Activate
                    erow = Worksheets("CALL OFF").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    Worksheets("CALL OFF").Cells(erow, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                    swbk.Activate

                Next i
            Next

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'        End If

'Done:
'    Exit Sub
'
'ErrHandling:
'            MsgBox "No file selected"

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Appears to not want to run" is vague. Is there a specific error message?

Comment: Sidenote - `Dim lastRow, i, erow As Integer` is declaring `lastRow` as `Variant` and `i` as `Variant`. You want to write that as `Dim lastRow As Integer, i as Integer, erow as Integer`.

Comment: My bad. I will ensure to include the error messages next time and thanks for the note on declaring. Honestly, I just saw this done on another bit of code I 'borrowed'. Figuring it was just a neater way of declaring, I did the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifing the parent on the copy range.

```
Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "B")).Select
```

Change to:

```
sws.Range(sws.Cells(i, "A"), sws.Cells(i, "B")).Copy
```

and remove the `Selection.Copy` line

But you can speed thing up a little and remove the loop by assigning the values directly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastRow As Long, erow As Long
Dim filename As String
Dim fname As Variant
Dim dwbk As Workbook, swbk As Workbook
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range

    Set dwbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set dws = dwbk.Sheets("Call OFF")

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandling

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FileArray = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select file(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

    For Each fname In FileArray

        Set swbk = Workbooks.Open(fname)
        Set sws = swbk.Sheets("Allocations")
        lastRow = sws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        erow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        dws.Cells(erow, 2).Resize(lastRow - 1, 2).Value = sws.Range(sws.Cells(2, 1), sws.Cells(lastRow, 2)).Value
    Next fname




    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'        End If

'Done:
'    Exit Sub
'
'ErrHandling:
'            MsgBox "No file selected"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. While it makes more sense to use that method when coping small amounts of data, when would it make more sense to use the loop?